# how to send MultiValueMap containing a file in a POST request to Spring rest web service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

I want to send a POST request which includes a file and another custom object using restTemplate. I have tried the code below, but didn't get it working as it is missing an `HtttpMessageConverter` for `java.io.File`

Is MultiValueMap the right choice to send both objects in one request? If not, any suggestions? If yes, then how do I get the message converter problem solved?

The client (adopted from [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/70845-sending-post-parameters-with-resttemplate-requests) and [here](http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=Sending%20Multipart%20File%20as%20POST%20parameters%20with%20RestTemplate%20requests)):

```
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> conv = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> ();
    conv.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
    conv.add(stringHttpMessageConverternew);

    rest.setMessageConverters(conv);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    File f = new File("testFile.txt");
    map.add("file", f);
    NewObject a = new NewObject("123", "xxx", "xxx",
            "blahblah", "5432");
    map.add("newObject", a);
    String result = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/test/upload", map, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadArtefact(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> o)
{
    logger.info("tesssting: " + o);
    File x = (File) o.get("file").get(0);
    logger.info("File name " + x.getName());
    NewObject a = (NewObject) o.get("newObject").get(0);
    logger.info("New Object: " + a);
    return "finished";


}
```

This is the error that I am getting on the client side:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.io.File]
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:317)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:275)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:264)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:204)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:751)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:540)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:503)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:331)
at uk.ac.ncl.rest.Test.main(Test.java:47)
```

and these two lines are logged on the server side:

```
2015-02-24 16:44:14.772  WARN 38776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate deserialization for type [map type; class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]]
2015-02-24 16:44:14.772  WARN 38776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate deserialization for type [map type; class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap, [simple type, class java.lang.Object] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap, [simple type, class java.lang.Object] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I spend so much time on this error!

FormHttpMessageConverter has 3 converters for parts:

1. ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter - writes byte[].class
2. StringHttpMessageConverter - String.class
3. ResourceHttpMessageConverter - org.springframework.core.io.Resource.class - here is the trick

Instead of putting file itself, you should put it as Resource:

```
File file = new File("some_path");
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(file);
map.add("file", resource);
```

FileSystemResource is from package org.springframework.core.io

Comment: I was making the same mistake. Thanks for saving my time!

Comment: For those, who handling incoming Http request with multipart file from gateway microservice to another microservice, you should use `InputStreamResource(yourMultipartIncomingFile.getInputStream()))`